# Downloading map service from ArcGIS web service as features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, map-service

I imported FEMA's Advisory Base Flood Elevation (ABFE) layer. It is an ArcGIS Web Service over the internet.  I can view it on the map, but it is listed as not selectable, and I cannot export sub layers, and I cannot view the attributes table.  It seems to be locked somehow.  I need to convert this layer into a standard layer that I can clip and manipulate.

Comment: Can you add a link to the service, that you are accessing, or from where you imported the data.

Comment: https://abfe.services.femadata.com/arcgis/rest/services/ABFE_pub/ABFE_06202013/MapServer